# How to update data in subViews of the mainView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Good day everyone!
The question is "How to update subViews data?"
I manage to add subview into the mainView like this:

```
        currenWeatherView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    currenWeatherView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    CGRect view1Hrame;
    view1Hrame.origin.x = 230*i;
    view1Hrame.origin.y = 0;
    view1Hrame.size = self.currenWeatherView.frame.size;

    weatherViewController *view1 = [[weatherViewController alloc] initWithForecast:[[Forecast alloc] initWithForecastInSelectedCity: theCity]]; 

    [view1.view setFrame: view1Hrame];

    [currenWeatherView addSubview: view1.view];
```

and then i want to change data like this

```
        for (weatherViewController *theView in weatherViewControllerArray) {
        [theView.self labelWeekTapped:2];
```

but theView is just a view not a class instance((

please help.

Comment: You should add a property to your view controller to which you assign the view.

Comment: No `@property`, you need to keep a reference to the view.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) weatherViewController *id;

Comment: something like this in weatherViewController class?

Comment: Yes something like that, but never use `id` the variable name.

Comment: What class does `-labelWeekTapped:` exist on? Also, you better not be naming your frames hrames. Take you time when writing code.

Comment: -labelWeekTapped: exist in weatherViewController class. I will be more accurate, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a private properties in your viewcontroller .m file:

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)  weatherViewController *weatherViewController; 

@end
```

Then assign the controller top that property:

```
currenWeatherView.clipsToBounds = NO;
currenWeatherView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

CGRect view1Hrame;
view1Hrame.origin.x = 230*i;
view1Hrame.origin.y = 0;
view1Hrame.size = self.currenWeatherView.frame.size;

self.weatherViewController = [[weatherViewController alloc] initWithForecast:[[Forecast alloc] initWithForecastInSelectedCity: theCity]]; 

[self.weatherViewController.view setFrame: view1Hrame];

[currenWeatherView addSubview: self.weatherViewController.view];
```

Now in the code where you need to update just call:

```
[self.weatherViewController labelWeekTapped:2];
```

---

Just a side note, in Objective-C class should always start with a capital, thus `weatherViewController` should be `WeatherViewController`.

The property then should always start with a non-capital letter.

Comment: Thank you for answer! May be i did write not quite correct question. There will be a lot of views:

Comment: for (City *theCity in app.commonCityList) {
    currenWeatherView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    CGRect view1Hrame;
    view1Hrame.origin.x = 230*i;
    view1Hrame.origin.y = 0;
    view1Hrame.size = self.currenWeatherView.frame.size;
    weatherViewController *view1 = [[weatherViewController alloc] initWithForecast:[[Forecast alloc] initWithForecastInSelectedCity: theCity]]; 
    [view1.view setFrame: view1Hrame];
    if (theCity.forecast != nil) {
        [view1 returnViewForCurrentForecast];
    }
    [currenWeatherView addSubview: view1.view];
}

Comment: is there be enough one property for this? currenWeatherView - is scrollView.
P.S. thank you for side note :) i will remember. sorry for comments like this - i cant answer my own question(

Comment: Then keep all the create view controller in a local array.

Comment: Yes, i did think this way too. [code] @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *weatherViewControllerArray;  but when i try to do [code]         for (weatherViewController *theView in weatherViewControllerArray) {
            [theView labelWeekTapped:2];
        } it does not affect subViews

Comment: Did you initialize the `weatherViewControllerArray`, like in the `viewDidLoad` as `weatherViewControllerArray =[NSMutableArray array]`

Comment: Yes! I works! I didn't do this [code] weatherViewControllerArray =[NSMutableArray array] [/code]